# Multiplayer FPS Architecture

Tags: architecture, server, game-development

I'm creating a multiplayer game and have been having some trouble creating a good architecture for the server side.

So far on the server we store a list of player which are the actively connected players, the main way they interact with each other is by shooting each other with guns. To facilitate this I decided that a gun would only be able to fire, and upon firing a `Referee` will check if the hitscan is colliding with an enemy and refer to the current game mode `TimedDeathMatch` which contains the rules about how much damage to assign to the player.

The complexity arises when we also need to tell each client to play the "gun fired" sound effect at a 3d point in space. In this situation I made it so that the `Referee` also manages this process. After looking back at the `Referee` I realized it does the following:

1. Manages weapon interactions
2. Manages networked sound
3. Manages the current state of the game (Preparation, Live, Complete)
4. Facilitates chatbox messaging from client to server.
5. Facilitates announcements from the server (who won the game)

Due to this the `Referee` code has become quite long and is doing multiple things at once. I was thinking of creating an `AudioEngineer`, `Announcer`, `Messenger` and then allocating some of those processes to them so it's easier to understand.

I'd like to get some feedback about how I'm structuring my server side architecture here, and possible simpler alternatives. I'd also like to know if my naming convention of modelling after job titles/people is alright to do.

Comment: You are thinking mainly in terms of classes. If you instead think in terms of *what should the computer do?* and then figure out how to divide it into classes later, does that change anything?

Comment: What is the main purpose of a Referee? and why is it called Referee if that's its main purpose? is it just a cute nickname?

Comment: The information required to play the sound is where, when, and what. Where does that information reside?

Comment: @user253751 The purpose of the Referee is to be a layer between the players and the ruleset. The players can fire weapons, and upon firing the Referee is notified of the source, target and weapon type, from there it assigns damage based on the ruleset. The entire server side is designed the same way that sports like soccer or basketball organize themselves.

Comment: @candied_orange one example would be a player firing their weapon, on fire my thought was that the `AudioEngineer` would then store the location of that player along with which weapon they fired, eventually sending that to the client side to make the sound happen.

Comment: "The entire server side is designed the same way that sports like soccer or basketball organize themselves" - Why? Is the computer like a sports game - does the CPU run around on a field and kick a ball? No, it operates completely differently and I don't see why it should have to be the same. We may as well try to design a sports game where the players shout ones and zeroes at the referee.

Comment: @cuppajoeman I'm not asking where you could store it. I'm asking where this infomation already naturally exists. Asking me about `AudioEngineer` boils down to asking me if I think it's a good name. Let's talk about what knows what it needs.

Comment: This sounds almost like a "_Dungeons and Dragons_"-type approach, where players tell the game-master what they want to do, then the game-master (or "_`Referee`_") tells a story that tries to make it all work with the rules.

Comment: @user253751 I decided to organize it like this because when new (or old) developers join then it's easy for them to know where to look for things because they already know how sports games work. For example, if we want to modify the code when one player shoots another player, then we would look in the `Rulebook` because depending on the current rules it might instagib the player or just do 10 damage.

Comment: @cuppajoeman and the flag that players have to capture is called a `Ball`, the game level should be called a `SoccerPitch`, individual polygons in the level rendering are called `BladeOfGrass`? Or do you call them `Flag`, `Level` and `Polygon` respectively?

Comment: @user253751 I see so it's more about what they actually are rather than what I want them to be, is that right?

Comment: @cuppajoeman I think you surely know the answer to whether the flag class should be called `Flag` or `Ball` :) ..... Actually, some games do have mis-named classes because the game changed while they were writing it. If your game used to have a ball but after 6 months your manager decided to change it to a flag, I wouldn't blame you for still calling it Ball in the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've fallen into the trap of deciding that each noun should be a class, rather than each class being a class. Usually people with this syndrome make a class for each noun in their program - Player, Weapon, Level - but you seem to have gotten your nouns from a televized game of sportsball instead - Referee, AudioEngineer, Announcer. I'm not really sure where you got that idea.

Regardless, "make a class for each noun" is generally bad advice. Yes, classes are nouns, roughly speaking, but you still want to use them when they are useful and not use them when they aren't useful, just like anything. You don't make one on habit just because you see a noun somewhere.

You did, and now you are confused about what to do with all these useless classes with no actual meaning.

My suggestion: Delete them (you can keep the code) and think about what you want the computer to do, then implement that. You don't want the computer to pretend to be an audio engineer - you want it to play audio.

*In games*, it's not uncommon to end up with a big "god class" that includes lots of game logic. This sounds like your Referee class. IMO, this is a sign that the code shouldn't be in any class at all, but you're using a language that makes you put it in a class anyway.

You should still use other classes where it makes sense. You could make the chatbox a separate thing, since it has nothing to do with gameplay. You might be able to make the game state (preparation, live, complete) a separate thing, depending on what that means for your game. In fact, your game state manager (tournament?) could just `new` a whole new game (round?) every time it wants to start one.

---

For your audio problem, there's a relevant pattern, which is the *observer* pattern (also called *listener*). You can make an interface like GunshotListener and then your gunshot code (whichever class that is in) holds a list of references to GunshotListeners. When a player shoots a gun, the gunshot code does something like `for(gsl in gunshotListeners) {gsl.onGunShot(player, coordinates);}`

For practicality, maybe that's too specific because there are 200 things that happen in your game and 200 one-off listener classes is too many. Maybe you'd do better with SoundEffectListener instead, and it would be `for(sel in soundEffectListeners) {sel.onSoundEffect(coordinates, GUNSHOT_SOUND_EFFECT);}`

Then, when creating a game, you would create the networked sound system (as well as all the other stuff like the chatbox system) and register it as a listener by adding it to the list. If you wanted a different sound system you could add that one instead, and if you wanted no sound system you could just not add one.

---

Personally (and this might be controversial) I would put gunshot code wherever is most convenient for your game. Shooting is not something the gun does. In real life, guns shoot, but in computer life, the computer calculates the hitscan based on the type of gun and the shape of the level and the location of the other players, and the gun isn't actually very important in the process. Perhaps if the guns in your game are completely different from each other, then it makes sense to put it in the gun class so it can be overridden for each gun type. Then again, perhaps not. Many games would have put this code in the main game class, the level class (because it accesses level geometry) or GunshotCalculator.

I don't see why you need something special called a Referee. The player can't cheat by uploading their own gun class, right? I hope they can't, since they could upload a gun class that formats the server's hard disk when it shoots. So you know what the guns do, and you know they don't allow cheating, because you didn't write code to make them cheat, so you don't need an extra class to make sure they don't cheat.

Comment: I think you've nailed it on the head with this answer, I seem to be modelling my architecture around real life rather than what I want to the computer to do. Do you think you could expand upon why it's a good idea to design your code based on what you want the computer to do?

Comment: I think the short answer is ultimately because the computer is going to do it?

Comment: indeed. @cuppajoeman the point of your program is to tell the computer how to do an FPS game. It doesn't matter how many fancy nouns your program has, if it doesn't tell the computer how to do an FPS game. That should be the first and foremost goal of the program.

Comment: @user253751 I see what you're saying I think my problem is that I'm imagining that the program *is* an FPS game, not something which is attempting to tell the computer how to do an FPS game. That's what the code is right or is it the FPS game itself ?

Comment: @cuppajoeman well, the word "game" is ambiguous. The program isn't a game like Broncos vs Wallabies, but the program is a game like rugby. Nothing wrong with having classes like Gun and PlayerCharacter - it's Referee and AudioEngineer that are weird. You might still benefit from remembering that the instance of Gun is not an actual gun, but still just a block of data in computer memory that helps the computer remember about a virtual gun.

Comment: When you think that a Player is a real player and a Gun is a real gun, it leads to questions like "does a gun shoot, or does a player shoot a gun?" and then you get confusion about whether the `shoot` method belongs in Player or Gun. Then I metaphorically shake you back to reality and tell you to stop it - the `shoot` method goes wherever is convenient to make the program work.

Answer (score 1):

The core idea of multi player games, at least where there is any competition or reason to cheat, is to never trust the client.

Using this model the client is simply a dumb client. It sends mouse and keyboard events to the server, the server runs the game code, and returns the state for all players. I.e. player positions, health, animation states, sounds etc. So programming the server should in principle be no different from programming the game locally. I do not really see the need for a "Referee", since that would only be useful if you could guarantee a valid game state, and if you have that, what usefulness does the referee have?.

To improve latency it is common to deviate from this model slightly, so that each client maintains an ephemeral state of the game world. So if a player fires his gun his local client can play the sound immediately. The server may decide that he in fact was out of ammo, and did *not* fire. But that should mainly occur if the player tries to cheat, or there is severe packet loss. You can also try to predict enemy movement etc, and accept that they might 'teleport' to their correct position when the "correct" position is received from the server.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, but we're already aware of anti-cheat mechanisms, server side lag compensation and client side interpolation. The question is more about how we can structure the server code from an architectural point of view. To answer your question, the referee just sits between players actions and the rulset, and assigns damage and knockback accordingly

Comment: @cuppajoeman I still do not see the need for a separate `referee`, at least I would not call it that. The problem is that it would easily turn into a good object, responsible for everything in the game. I would instead put logic into the actions. A player shoots, the shoot action checks ammo, checks for hits, applies damage etc.

Answer (score 1):

This is the sort of thing that is remarkably hard to do well. The general subject of "rollback netcode" is worth doing your reading on, as it can make or break the player experience. You might also benefit from studying a game for which the code is available such as Quake.

In relation to

> naming convention of modelling after job titles/people is alright to do.

Sort of. The problem is that in OO design we prefer to talk about things *within* the domain, and in the average FPS there aren't referees and announcers etc. It sounds like you've ended up with a ["god object"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), which is easily done when a project grows without a good structure.

Normally you'd structure a game around "actors", which are things able to act in the game - players or non-player-characters. Possibly delegate further to have the *weapon* as an actor, so that you can have fireWeapon() do various different things. That would normally be where all the hitscan detection and allocation of results would go. You can make individual projectiles actors as well, although that can have very bad performance when you have a lot of them.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yes we're eventually going to implement server side lag compensation, and we found that the source multiplayer networking article has a good read on it as well. I think the reason why I was afraid of having allocation of results inside of the gun code was because in my head a real life gun doesn't do that. How should I change my mindset so that I'm not modeling everything around real-life things?

Comment: I guess one thing that I get confused about is what the domain of an FPS really is. Is the domain a real life battle with contestants, shooting each other with real guns? If that's the case then if A shot B, then there shouldn't be a `Referee` involved, the bullet either hits the other player or not and the bullet deals damage just by hitting the other player. Or is the domain of an FPS a simulation where players send user command and the server sends back game states to the client to update their view (omniscient view point).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be missing an 'Event' model in your design.  You talk about managing the state of the game, which is important, but things like 'player A gun fired' are pretty hard to model using state alone.  You would need to essentially model the 'bullet' as it traverses in through space over time.  Even at a high framerate and very low latency this is unworkable.  So if you've got something that works, you are surely using some sort of event-like approach, you just haven't embraced it in your design (or at least you haven't explained how you do.)

Once you start thinking about it that way, you should start to see that the current state of the game is essentially the initial state after all events have been applied to it.  In addition, each players actions are events that change the state of the game.

Essentially, the server becomes the clearing house for events.  It receives updates from the client and applies them to the 'canonical' model of the game state.  It then distributes relevant events to each client.  The clients can then apply these updates to their copy of the game model (or portion of it.)

In this approach, a player firing a gun is fairly simple.  The client initiates the event 'my gun fired' with the location it was fired from and the direction it was fired in.  This event is sent to the server which then determines who or what was hit and updates its model.  It distributes the 'gun fired' event to the other clients, changes to the model due to that event, and also other updates to the model that occurred during that time.

The playing of a sound then simply becomes one of the things that the client does on processing the 'gun fired' event.  Whether you want the event to include the sound to play or you just allow the client to decide what sound is associated with the event is up to you.

It sounds like your `Referee` is doing a lot of the event management.  I don't think it's a good name, but the more important factor is modelling around events.  It's also a good idea to provide a way to retrieve the full state of the game and/or previously sent events from the server.  If a client falls behind in processing or has missed events, this allows them to get back in sync with the server.